# Jupyter notebook, matplotlib visualization not showing up

Tags: python, microsoft-windows, jupyter

I am a new Emacs user and proceeded to the install following the tutorial at: https://realpython.com/emacs-the-best-python-editor/#integration-with-jupyter-and-ipython. Now I am running a Jupyter Notebook, again as described in the link above, but I am getting the following error:

```
 ein:cel--append-mime-type no viewer found in mailcap
```

Do you have any idea what I should do? I tried to solve it using https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook/issues/671 but couldn't find the recommended fix (customize-group-ein-image on) to run.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

For information, I am running Emacs on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should `M-x customize RET` and look for "mailcap mime".
- Navigate to "Mailcap User Mime Data".
- INS new entry.
- Clock in Choice:`Value Menu` and choose Shell command.
- type in *Choice Shell command:* sxiv %s
- type in *MIME Type:* image/*

Save the customization. Now, when jupyter looks for how to visualize an image file it will use `sxiv`. As the procedure we would like to emulate is upon a string-directory, the format is `sxiv %s(tring)`. Just like we would type in a terminal to visualize an image with sxiv, e.g., sxiv ~/path/to/my/image. The path is provided by a temporary file created by jupyter as the output of the cell.

I hope it's clear.

**ALTERNATIVE (tested)**:
in `$HOME/.mailcap` file, put the following text and save it:

```
image/*; magick display %s
```

In Emacs, `M-x customize RET`, look for `ein inline images`, and `Toggle` to `on (non-nil)` the `Ein Output Area Inlined Images:` area.

```
Ein Output Area Inlined Images: Toggle  on (non-nil)
    State : SET for current session only.
   Turn on to insert images into buffer.  Default spawns external viewer.
Groups: Ein
```

If you have imagemagick installed (an image viewer and manipulator), you should be able to go to an ein-jupyter session, in a jupyter notebook, and see images inlined:
[image]

**EDIT: include author MWE**
Your example works fine here, after this setup.
[image]

**NOTES:**

- You can use whatever image viewer software you would like, `sxiv`,`imagemagick`, `gimp`, etc.